# How to change css style locally and save this changes

Tags: css, html

i have an webapp and i need to onclick change css style, but i need to save this change in the webapp instaled into the phone of my user, and only in his phone. The javascript for onclick change css style it's working but i don't have no idea to how to save this css changes.

Can somebody help me with this?

Since now thanks

Comment: save it in local storage and have your app read local storage on (re-)launch

Answer (score 0):

In general CSS styles can't be directly saved on an HTML client.

What you can do is make an Ajax call back to your server and save the information there. The next time the user asks for the page send HTML with the appropriate style class already on the element you wish to style based on the saved information.

There are several hackish client side possibilities involving JavaScript & cookies or local storage but I would avoid that sort of solution if at all possible since it's very likely to lead to an annoying flicker as the page loads and renders styled one way and then the JavaScript finally runs and corrects the style.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment:

```
    el1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        el2.style.color = 'red';
        localStorage['color'] = el2.style.color; 
    })
```

And then on startup:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if (localStorage['color']) {
            el2.style.color = localStorage['color'];
        }
    }
```

Of course, you may want to add error checking and fallbacks as appropriate.

Comment: And if this JavaScript runs on a fast client you may not notice the flicker. On a slow client such as a phone that is running a lot of other apps at the same time, or is old it may appear in the original color briefly before the JavaScript executes. The importance of this is of course up to the OP to decide.